# running git from crontab - permission denied

Tags: linux, git, unix, cron

I've looked this up and found lots of answers but I am a unix/linux dummy.  Not able to follow peoples instructions.  Not sure which files to edit etc..

**need simple step by step instructions here**

I have a shell file set up like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &>> /var/www/nginx/yokohama/laravel/storage/cron.log
today='date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S';

cp /var/www/nginx/yok/yok_data.xml /var/www/nginx/yok/yok_XML_Files/backup-$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").xml
git add /var/www/nginx/yok/yok_XML_Files/backup-$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").xml
git commit -m "cool test"
git push origin staging
```

if I run it manually as root it works and we're all good. but doesnt work through my cron..

here is my crontab

```
* * * * *  /usr/bin/sh /var/www/nginx/yok/laravel/commit_data.sh
```

In my cron.log I'm getting
`Permission denied (publickey).^M`

How can I fix this?  Simple instructions.

Comment: "if I run it manually as root it works". And what if you manually run it as yourself instead of root?

Comment: the only account i have access to is root..  unless i decide to make a new user on this staging server

Comment: Generate a pair of ssh keys for your root user or your crontab user account and deploy the public key to the remote git server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Permission denied (publickey).^M
```

The `^M` at the end that your script might have `\r\n` eol (end of lines) characters instead of `\n`: try [`dos2unix`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html).

Also make sure your script is executable:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/nginx/yok/laravel/commit_data.sh
```

The [OP hamobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015571/hamobi) mentions another reason [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363052/running-git-from-crontab-permission-denied/38367526#comment64181449_38367526):

> problem even more basic. had to move users rsa key into bitbucket.

Comment: @hamobi OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.